# git checkout: what does this weird output mean?

Tags: git

When I checkout, I get:

```
me@localhost# git checkout master
D    deps/example
M    deps/example2
Switched to branch "master"
```

The man page doesn't mention this cryptic output. What does it mean?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

That's the output of `git status`; git is showing you that after checking out `master` there are still uncommited changes to your working copy (one modified file and one deleted file).

Check `man git-status`:

```
M = modified
A = added
D = deleted
R = renamed
C = copied
U = updated but unmerged
```

Comment: Hmm. I guess I'm confused because if I run 'git status' it says my working directory is clean.

Comment: @mwt if you change branches again do you still get those messages?

Comment: Yes. I get different ones for my master and topic, though.

Comment: Anyway, you're right, as I was able to git add -u the deleted directories and everything's better. Along with a couple of other confusing elements I won't bother with, the fact that git status was disagreeing with checkout's output was throwing me off. If you have any guesses about that, I'll be interested, but the main point is answered.