# What do the letters M, A, and D mean after git checkout

Tags: git

My console looks like this.

```
Switched to branch 'main'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
user@dyn-128-59-6-239 proj % git branch new_branch
user@dyn-128-59-6-239 proj % git checkout new_branch
M   file1.json
A   file2.yml
M   file3.yml
D   file4.yml
Switched to branch 'new_branch'
```

What do the letters M, A, and D mean to the left of the files listed?

I was expecting all the files would be identical to main on a fresh branch. Does this mean there are differences between main and the new branch for some reason?

Comment: Better match may be https://stackoverflow.com/q/4949652/11082165. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8691199/11082165 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/54828777/11082165 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/48304195/11082165 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/34540100/11082165

Comment: Why are there files that are modified or deleted after checking out into a brand new branch?

Comment: That's mentioned in the answer in the first link: _"git is showing you that after checking out [new_branch] there are still uncommited changes to your working copy"_. You switched branches, but still have a dirty working tree. You can run `git reset --hard HEAD` to change your working tree to match `new_branch` exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all documented [`man git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_output). The actual meaning depends whether the letter is in the first column or the second, but in general those indicate the changes against the current index:

- M - file is modified
- A - new file added
- D - file is deleted